# I want to fix this @stripe/stripe-js version error - StripeCustomCheckoutActions or StripeCustomCheckoutOptions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, stripe-payments, inertiajs, laravel-cashier

I have a Laravel React Inertia js typescript project. i installed the @stripe/stripe-js for that. its already work but i did npm update command and then display this issue

Build Frontend Production Assets 20240306104407667
Building the app using npm run build ...

> build
> tsc && vite build && vite build --ssr

node_modules/@stripe/react-stripe-js/dist/react-stripe.d.ts(704,55): error TS2724: '"/("My project url and location)/releases/20240306104407667/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/dist/index"' has no exported member named 'StripeCustomCheckoutActions'. Did you mean 'StripeCustomCheckoutOptions'?

how to solve that?

my node version is v18.15.0
npm version is 9.5.0

this is my package json versions

"@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^2.5.1",
"@stripe/stripe-js": "^3.0.7",

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.15",
    "@inertiajs/react": "^1.0.0",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
    "@types/node": "^18.13.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "@types/react-helmet": "^6.1.6",
    "@types/supercluster": "^7.1.3",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
    "axios": "^1.6.4",
    "laravel-vite-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.31",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^5.0.0"
},
```

i try to downgrade stripe-js versions but it not work

Comment: You probably want to reach out to Stripe Support or their Discord server to get help directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to down version of @stripe/stripe-js to 3.0.6 and @stripe/react-stripe-js to 2.5.0 and it work for me. The problem maybe is the conflict between two version of two library above.

Comment: thank you i will try to downgrade and test

Comment: yes, its work. that version working Thanks